# Spring security - httpbasic not working: What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to spring security. Try to use it for project with a rest backend. For my backend certain urls need to be open, certain urls need to have httpbasic auth / https and certain urls need a token authentication.

I'm trying to set this up using a test with web mvc. Trying to test it by using controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/auth/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void test(){
    System.err.println("Controller reached!");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/auth/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void test2(){
    System.err.println("Controller reached!");
}
```

My Spring Security Config locks like the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class FreeEndpointsConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/signup").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class HttpBasicAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login").hasAnyRole("USER")
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
}
```

My Test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootContext.class, WebSecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration 
public class AccountSecurityTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc securityMockMvc;

@Before
public void SetupContext() {    
    securityMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .apply(springSecurity()).build();
}

@Test
public void testSigInFree() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = post("/auth/signup");
    securityMockMvc.perform(post).andExpect(status().isOk());
}

@Test
public void testLoginHttpBasic() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = post("/auth/login");
    securityMockMvc.perform(post).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

The testmethod "testLoginHttpBasic" is green. But I would expect a failure, because i'm trying to configure / enforce httpbasic authentication. Where is my mistake?

Comment: That seems to be the default behaviour for Spring Security, it just includes a header in the response to tell the browser to display the login form again when login fails. You can easily test it in your browser too. I think that's not misleading, since you're testing a controller which is meant to be accessed by an end user. So when you develop a real login form, when user fails the login the response won't be 401, but you'll redirect him to a login failure page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/signup").permitAll()` 
to 
`http.antMatcher("/auth/signup").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()`

and

`http.antMatcher("/auth/login").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER")`
 to 
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login").hasAnyRole("USER")`.

Your second test will fail.

**Why do you need this change?**

`http.authorizeRequests()...` creates a `SecurityFilterChain` that matches every URL. As soon as one `SecurityFilterChain` matches the request all subsequent `SecurityFilterChain`s will never be evaluated. Hence, your `FreeEndpointsConfig` consumed every request.

With `http.antMatcher("...")` in place you restrict every `SecurityFilterChain` to a particular URL (pattern). Now `FreeEndpointsConfig` matches only `/auth/signup` and `HttpBasicAuthConfig` `/auth/login`.

**Small improvement**

You can make several URLs like paths to static resources (js, html or css) public available with `WebSecurity::configure`. Override `WebSecurity::configure` in your `WebSecurityConfig`

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/auth/signup");
}
```

and `FreeEndpointsConfig` isn't required anymore.